# Docker always download new dependencies from pom.xml

Tags: docker, maven

I have a simple Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-11
RUN mkdir /project
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "target/app.jar"]``
```

But everytime i run this, maven downloads all dependencies from central once again. Can I avoid that? How to do this?

Comment: Where should it take it from instead?

Comment: ideally it would fetch the repository from the local machine and download only if necessary to local machine too not to container

Comment: You haven't understood the concept of containers... those are separated OS's in some ways (simplifying a lot here)... every time you start the build new the cache inside the container is simply empty which in consequence is the reason that the deps will be downloaded... most of the time it's easier to build the app itself on your machine and copy only the resulting jar into the container....

Comment: Read more about containers and also  the section "Reusing the Maven local repository" at https://hub.docker.com/_/maven